# How does Spell Targeting work diagonally on a grid?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

Last session, our mage wanted to attack diagonally with a cube spell attack, *thunderwave*. Playing on a 5x5 grid map, my DM said he couldn't. He said the mage could only place the cube horizontally or vertically. Is this correct?

Comment: Is the grid hex or square (not entirely sure it matters, but may help).

Comment: Or upload a picture/drawing? I have a guess at what you mean, and there's already an answer making a *different*, incompatible guess at what you mean, which means that we're not all understanding your question the same. A diagram would help immensely.

Comment: He doesn't need to provide a picture.  The thuderwave is centered on the caster, which means the possibilities of what is and isn't a valid can easily be covered in an answer.

Comment: @J.A.Streich That's what I was thinking. I think the answer can be provided without specifics on grid design.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about attacking (which is a specific game term). It is about casting a particular spell, Thunder Wave, that is not an attack spell. I think the title needs to be edited to reflect this, because answers will be about Thunder Wave or spell areas of effect on a grid, nothing to do with attacking.

Comment: @Bloodcinder Made that edit - if OP doesn't agree, please roll back!

Comment: I swear there was a very similar question that I either answered or commented on but can't seem to find it.

Comment: @J.A.Streich We might understand how this works when the rules are being followed correctly, but we can't guess at what exact failure is leading to this question. We need to know more, because an answer needs to not just repeat what the text already says, but also be able to directly correct the error that has lead to the mis-application of the rules that lead to asking this question. And that error could be a number of different things that we should not guess about. E.g., the existing answer's explanation would *not* help if the error is what *I* guess it is, and vice versa.

Answer (score 7):

### Clear cut cases

The rules clearly allow the following, where the player is in the square with the * and the box indicates the cube.

[image: Centered on a side]
[image: Offset on a side]

The rules say the player is along a side, not a corner, so following is clearly illegal.

[image: Corner isn't allowed]

### DM Call

Now, 5e was designed with playing on the grid being an optional rule, so depending on the way the DM does translation, he can rule the following either legal or illegal depending.

[image: Cube at angle]

The DM may want to avoid ruling on the partial covered squares, and just say that cube has to "snap to the grid", or the DM may rule that any square in the effect or covered at least 1/2 or 1/4 is counted...  But the Rules as they written doesn't elaborate, as the whole use of the grid in 5e is an optional, although very common, rule.

Comment: "along a side, not a corner" - but a corner consists of tho sides, doesn't it? since the POO can be "anywhere on a face" (PHB p. 204) it seems it actually can be on the edge

Comment: The corner isn't on a face (which is a term of art in 3D modeling and mathematics).  The where two sides meet is an edge in math terms and a corner in common vernacular.  If I told you to set your books down on the top face of a table, you wouldn't try to balance them on the edge of the table at a 45 degree angle.

Comment: Your interpretation that a corner is not part of two faces simultaneously is understandable, but not specified in the rules.  Thus, calling it "clearly illegal" is presenting your interpretation as rules fact.

Answer (score 6):

The DMG has this to say on the matter (p. 251):

> The area of effect of a spell, monster ability, or other feature must
>   be translated onto squares or hexes to determine which potential
>   targets are in the area and which aren't. Choose an intersection of
>   squares or hexes as the point of origin of an area of effect, then
>   follow its rules as normal.

Depending on how you interpret "translating onto squares" this could go either way and is **in the hands of the DM**. *I personally* do not enforce "snapping to the grid", ie. forcing square and line effects to run parallel to the grid and use my best judgement on determining which creatures are affected.

Comment: I would agree with @Szega. By "snapping" to the grid, especially on a square grid you end up with "corridors" and would seem overly restrictive.

Comment: @J.A.Streich "You select a cube's point of origin, which lies anywhere
on a face of the cubic effect." PHB 204 on cube areas of effect. So it extends in one direction from you, not around you.

Answer (score 1):

Szega's answer is the one I would give.

To add to the "translating onto squares" he mentions, I draw and cut out a "mask" on a transparency for each common area of effect. If I haven't got a transparency I draw it on squared paper and use that.

Then I use these to determine what orientations are possible and who is in the area of effect by either holding them above the figures and judging it by eye or, if it is really contentious, removing the figures (making a mental note of where they were), placing the transparency on the grid in the orientation desired by the caster and then replacing the figures.

Comment: So that this is a real answer on its own, [it's preferable that it answer the question independently](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/should-i-be-requesting-people-answer-the-question-independently) by including any necessary statements, and not refer the reader to other answers (except perhaps to give due credit).